# Unity 5.3.0f4 : UI Button has stopped working on Android after playing long time

Tags: android, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I have  developed a game where all are working fine but after playing long time on Android , UI button is not calling the OnClick() function's code but change the color tint of pressed , normal and highlighted. And if I do that :-
(Android) setting->apps-> [myapp Name]-> clear data then everything is working fine again.So, how can I fix this problem in Unity?

Comment: could you share your button code implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! I find a solution. Just Go to EventSystem and Change the value of Drag Threshold from 5 to 20 and after build ,  I play about 6 hours and I cannot see any problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to provide any help here with no code or examples of anything. Are you using a 3rd party UI framework like NGUI or unity's UI system?

Best thing for you to do is play the game in unity for a while with mono or vs attached to Unity. Once this problem replicates itself in Unity you can see whats going on in the debugger. Or use adb to dump the log out from the phone.
See: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html

If you can't replicate this problem in Unity I would report it to Unity yourself as a bug with Android builds.

If you provide code or elaborate more on what you're exactly working with I can edit this answer later to hopefully help you.

Comment: I don't use any third party UI....I just use Unity UI system and the code is :      public GameObject starter;   public void force(){  starter.setActive(true);}

Comment: @KhandokerAnan I see that you found a solution. =)